# Are there single-word and generally accepted terms for the referents of the arguments in comparative clauses?

Tags: syntax, terminology, semantics

AFAIK, in any statement comparing two entities, there are typically at least three terms:

NPa stands for the thing compared

VG stands for nature of comparison

NPb stands for the thing that the referent of the first term is compared to.

Are there terms from linguistics or logic that constitute single words for each of the terms I've mentioned?

Comment: Are you asking about comparative (or equative or superlative) constructions in  natural languages, or about the philosophy of comparison? If the former, be advised that comparatives are legendary examples of complex syntax and semantics.

Comment: I'm asking about the semantics of comparison, ignoring syntax for the time being.

Comment: There have to be two propositions with independent quantifiers but the same metric. Each quantifier has different values . Comparison is deciding which of the values is larger, according to the metric.